# (Java) Transfering an Object to an application through Clipboard

Tags: java, serialization, clipboard

How can I copy a Java object (with a couple of fields) to my clipboard in Java, and what is the best way to store these fields? 
I have a simple object with a `ΗashΜap` for storage.

Also, I created a selection for this object, which it implements both `Transferable` and `ClipboardOwner`, as well as a `DataFlavor` for it.

What I'm trying to do is copy this object and paste it in another application. Keep in mind that I don't have access to the source code of this application, so I have to transfer this object in this *particular* way. Let's say this application is requiring these following fields:

- **Info**      (String)
- **Text** (String in UTF-8 Format)

However, copying and pasting this object to the other application doesn't seem to work.

Below you can see my classes:

**MyObject**:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyObject {

    private HashMap<Object, Object> data;

    public MyObject() 
    {
        data = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    }

    public void setData(Object field, Object value) 
    {
        data.put(field, value);
    }

}
```

**MyObjectFlavor**:

```java
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;

public class MyObjectFlavor extends DataFlavor {

    public MyObjectFlavor() 
    {
        super(MyObject.class, null);
    }  

}
```

**MyObjectSelection**:

```java
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class MyObjectSelection implements Transferable, ClipboardOwner {

    final static DataFlavor myObjectFlavor = new MyObjectFlavor();
    final static DataFlavor[] supportedDataFlavors = { myObjectFlavor };

    private MyObject myObject;

    public MyObjectSelection(MyObject myObject) 
    {
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor dataFlavor)
            throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException 
    {
        if (!isDataFlavorSupported(dataFlavor)) {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(dataFlavor);
        }

        // Passing data in a ByteArrayOutputStream.

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
        objectStream.writeObject(myObject);
        return byteStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() 
    {
        return supportedDataFlavors;
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor dataFlavor) 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < supportedDataFlavors.length; i++) {
            if (supportedDataFlavors[i].equals(dataFlavor)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard arg0, Transferable arg1) 
    {
        // Lost ownership.
    }

}
```

Finally, my **Main** class is:

```java
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        MyObjectSelection selection = new MyObjectSelection(myObject);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard ();

        String myUtfString = "This is a String in UTF-8";

        myObject.setData("Info", "This is a Java Object.");
        myObject.setData("Text", new ByteArrayInputStream(myUtfString.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

    }
}
```

I'm sorry for the long post, but I think providing all classes will help. I hope this question is not specific. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What speaks against json or xml ?

Comment: @Marged Please be more specific. I don't have access to the other application, so I just have to cooperate with it.

Comment: That is an important detail, add it to your question

Comment: @Marged Thanks - done! :)